# Sony PVM Connections / Composite Signale

Tags: video, crt-monitor, s-video, composite-video

I am trying to learn more about different video formats. I have a SONY PVM9044QM and want to understand the different connection options.

So I understand, that Y/C equals S-Video input.
But what does Lina A and Line B, as well as "Video In" mean. Is this Composite?
RGB Component is clear though. So that means I can connect:

- S-Video
- Composite (if I see this correctly)
- Component / RGB

So when I have a Composite Cable with Video/L/R means, I put the cable into Video IN (Line A) and Audio In (Line A+B)?

[image]

Comment: I have the same crt at school (9041qm one with lower res) and as someone that knows a bit about broadcast TV. I think these two are probably for multiple inputs. İn fact they are! https://archive.org/details/sony_PVM-9041QM_9044QM_Service_Manual the first few pages explain switch ing between inputs. Btw i dont remember exactly but some trinitrons require specific bnc terminators or picture will be foggy.

Comment: You could have posted the front side too. Or download the manual. But the device seems to have two sets of composite inputs called A and B, and input A supports S-video.

Comment: İ also strongly suggest you to learn how to component/rgb mod your console then ntsc calibrate your monitor using 240p test suite available for most consoles. if you get the chance. Video looks perfect in infinite contrast ratio crt TV. Ps dont forhet to remember that 4:3 and 16:9 switch on the back!

Comment: Absolutly agree, that I read about too and I am eager to learn. Currently I am in need to connect an Amstrad CPC and a C64. Using an OSSC for a TFT, I still want to make use of the CRT. The OSSC does not have composite/SVideo and therefore I could test these older devices on the CRT directly

Comment: @DeltaOscarUniform Thank you, I just looked up the manual you posted, even though I am still missing a lot of background (no suprise here.) so i understand now, that the Audio OUTs are looping the input signal back out, so you can record it somewhere. Still begs the question where I connect the audio connector cables when I use composite; I think my logic is not correct here as the cable setup I might need is different from what i think

Comment: @retronexus I think you need RCA/3.5mm to quarter inch jack adapters and connect them to the audio in terminals in line a/b or component. Here is my advice. Instead of buying adapters that are always crap (they always get loose and make super noisy buzzy sounds whenever they actually work. I know from experience...) just get some wire strippers and solder the wires from the source cable to the quarter inch jack. You can try twisting the copper wire within the cable but they always get untangled then short circıüt. Also audio out exists because these are field monitors for betacam/jvc ky19 etc

Comment: @retronexus actually never mind. Just connect your ps1 to a good quality headphones. Something like ath mx series (mdr v6 and 7506 are bad for casual listening. They just mute everything other than voice and you can barely fix them by time consumünt equalizer settings)

Comment: Excellent... I was totally on the wrong track regarding the connectors ( guess to many connectors and theory in one day). Superb... thank you! Now I know where to start I think!

Comment: @retronexus nope this was just the intro to the land of retro pc. Now you have to know how to make breakout cables (who also need diodes) from propiretary video connectors to the vga/scart then if you really dare get a 15khz television video from 31 khz computer vga from graphics cards through custom drivers Unless you choose easy route with active adapters. Also good thing this crt is multi format!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are four groups of connectors (Line A, Line B, RGB/Component, and Ext Sync), and each group should be treated as a whole.

As it's a monitor, I assume you have an "out" for each "in", and the "out" is just connected to the corresponding "in" (because "out" otherwise doesn't make sense for a monitor).

You'll be able to choose between three sources, "Line A", "Line B", and "RGB Component". "Line A" accepts both S-Video (Y/C) and Composite (Video) in addition to audio, "Line B" only accepts Composite (Video) in addition to audio, and "RGB/component" accepts either RGB or component (R-Y/Y/B-Y) in addition to audio. You'll be able to select for the latter which type it is.

In addition to everything, there's the option to have external sync signals (whatever kind, you'd need the manual for that).

> So when I have a Composite Cable with Video/L/R means, I put the cable into Video IN (Line A) and Audio In (Line A+B)?

It means you decide if you want to connect it to "Line A" or "Line B", and then you connect it to "Video" and "Audio In". Say you connect it to "Line A", then you can connect a second composite signal from some other computer to "Line B".

Comment: EXT SYNC IN will be most useful when hooking up an RGBS signal, such as from an Amiga, Apple IIgs, or SCART compatible RGB source. You'll just need the right cable from the machine to 4xBNC.

Answer (score 4):

> So when I have a Composite Cable with Video/L/R means, I put the cable
> into Video IN (Line A) and Audio In (Line A+B)?

It looks to be mono audio only so you can either get an adapter that connects left and right audio together or run your stereo audio through a separate amplifier. Either Audio A or B (but not both) will be selected along with the corresponding video signal using the front panel input selection buttons.

There's a brochure/specification sheet available e.g. [here](http://www.productionav.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Sony-9-Inch-Preview-Monitor-Manual.pdf) which might be easier to start with than the service manual.

Comment: Aaaah of course its mono.... so the connector seems to be an RCA connector.

Comment: @retronexus Looks like it ... and confirmed by the service manual.  Nice find. If you can get S-Video or RGB out of your consoles you'll get a much better picture than a composite connection.

Comment: Pretty happy with the monitor, just was lucky getting it from a TV station nearby. Appreciate all your support!